# How to set background-repeat : no-repeat in element.style

Tags: java, jquery, css

Regarding the element below

```
<div style="display: block; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 
            url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/south_carolina.png";) 
            repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: relative; padding: 0px; 
            width: 615px; height: 615px;">
```

How can I edit the element.style? I want the `background-repeat : no-repeat;` not sure from where to set it.

```
element {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/south_carolina.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 615px;
    height: 615px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorthand for background. Where it says `repeat` change to `no-repeat`.

element { display: block; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/south_carolina.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: relative; padding: 0px; width: 615px; height: 615px; }

Answer (score 0):

In this same line? Use `no-repeat`:

```
element { display: block; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/south_carolina.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: relative; padding: 0px; width: 615px; height: 615px; }
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$('element-selector').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
```

Where `element-selector` is the css query to select your element.